# two kind of javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm new in javascript.

I want to what's the difference between this

```
 function aa(){
    //code
}

    function bb(){
      //code
    }
```

and this

```
var b = {
        aa : function (){
    //code
      },
       bb: function () {
        //code
   }
};
```

I know about function. but I don't know about the another one.

What's it called and what's differences?? which one is better and faster??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one creates two named functions: `aa` and `bb`.

The second one creates an object called `b` that has two properties: `aa` and `bb`, both of which have anonymous functions as values.

They do different things, so you can't really say which one is "better".

Comment: if I called aa() vs b.aa().. which function call will b faster or better?

Comment: @Raymond: Better? What do you mean?

Comment: sorry for my english. What I mean is which function will be executed faster? I mean performance, script loading, etc..

Comment: @Raymond: They're the same.